# Incorrect memory hp ProLiant ML110 G6 in VMWare

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant

My ESXi server is report that it only has 8GB where as it actually has 16GB. I do not have physical access to the machine. How could I go about verifying this information? I am currently using the following firmware:

IPMI Version:   2.0
Firmware Version:   4.21
Hardware Version:   1.0

Could it be that I have faulty memory?

Comment: You want to access

Comment: How can I verify how much memory it really has? I have SSH access to VMWare ESXi as well as access to vSphere and venter. How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say you want to access the iLO console which will show if the memory is detected by the server.  Chances are it isn't so you'll need to go hands-on anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want hardware access if you think what the hypervisor is telling you is incorrect.

Generally you would use the remote management of your server to look at the memory modules installed. Possibly reboot with a memory test image or another OS to see what it finds.